# move to vs move on to the next topic/lesson/item/activity

Tags: grammaticality

I'd like to know if both of the following sentences are correct.

> Let's move to the next topic.
>   Let's move on to the next topic.

If yes, is there any difference in meaning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Theyre different ways of thinking about the arrangement of the topics. Almost definitely not alternated between with any intention. In other words, he most likely wants to communicate the exact same thing regardless of which one he uses.

They are both grammatically correct. And they definitely also effectively mean the same thing. They will almost definitely be perceived similarly.

I suppose "move on" alludes to some chronology. Move to is more about physical space. The concept of moving on always has to do with time and definitely implies a past and probably necessitates it. (similarly, "move to", definitely implies another location which you are moving *from*.)

Using the individual meanings of *move* and *on*, *move* and *move on* would effectively mean the same thing.

Cause where else would you move. in? are we moving *in* to a new topic?

But when both *move* and *on* are used together, they have a different meaning.

Both would be grammatically correct, and almost definitely both would successfully convey what you intend to, but *move on* would "refer" to the previous events as a chronology. *Move* would refer them as items on a map/chart or some more physical concept of the things as points in space rather than points in time (or series of events in time).

I went ahead and looked this up. One of the definitions of "on" is "in the course of (a journey)". I believe thats the meaning of "on" being used here by default.

If you said "We moved on to the sand", though, with no other context, it would be assumed you were talking about physical space and would be interpreted the same as "we moved to the sand".

Comment: Thank you. My teacher always says "let's move on to the next topic." And then yesterday, he just said, "let's move to the next topic." So I wondered.